# python How to convert a dictionary string to the corresponding dictionary?

Tags: python, json, string

I cannot convert a dictionary string back to dictionary with ast.literal_eval(). I guess the reason might be there are lots of nulls in the dictionary string. One example will be like

```
'{"paper_id": "94550656", "_pdf_hash": "42b3e1bd9c4740192f22d8725d470218e86301c8", "abstract": [], "body_text": [], "bib_entries": {"BIBREF0": {"title": "Solving ratio-dependent predator-prey system with constant effort harvesting using homotopy perturbation method", "authors": [{"first": "R", "middle": ["G"], "last": "Abdoul", "suffix": ""}, {"first": "A", "middle": [], "last": "Barari", "suffix": ""}, {"first": "D", "middle": ["D"], "last": "Ganji", "suffix": ""}], "year": 2008, "venue": "J. Math. Prob. Eng", "link": "16827035"}, "BIBREF1": {"title": "Numerical analysis of strongly nonlinear oscillation systems using He\'s max-min method", "authors": [{"first": "H", "middle": [], "last": "Babazadeh",.....
```

how can I convert this to the normal dictionary for further processing?
########################################

here's the code:

```
json_list = []
with open(s2orc_path, 'r') as s2orcReader:
for line in s2orcReader.readlines():
    json_list.append(line)
s2orc_samples = json.dumps(json_list)
s2orc_data = json.loads(s2orc_samples)
```

After this when I try to do `ast.literal_eval(s2orc_data[0])`, it gives me the error `ValueError: malformed node or string`

Comment: could you replace `null` to `None` and do it again?

Comment: Is it actually *JSON*? (If so @Roharui there will also be issues with e.g. `true`/`True`.) Give a [mre].

Comment: yes it works after replacement. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

data = """{"paper_id": "94550656", "_pdf_hash": "42b3e1bd9c4740192f22d8725d470218e86301c8", "abstract": [], "body_text": [], "bib_entries": {"BIBREF0": {"title": "Solving ratio-dependent predator-prey system with constant effort harvesting using homotopy perturbation method", "authors": [{"first": "R", "middle": ["G"], "last": "Abdoul", "suffix": ""}, {"first": "A", "middle": [], "last": "Barari", "suffix": ""}, {"first": "D", "middle": ["D"], "last": "Ganji", "suffix": ""}], "year": 2008, "venue": "J. Math. Prob. Eng", "link": "16827035"}}}"""""
dictionary_data = json.loads(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use json.loads for this:

```
import json

str = "'[{"age":"luke", "id":0}, {"age":"bob", "id":1}]'"
dict = json.loads(str)
print(str) # [{u'age': u'luke', u'id': 0}, {u'age': u'bob', u'id': 1}]
```

Comment: then you data might be invallid, maybe you used None instead of null

Comment: just make sure the json is valid

Comment: I didn't make the data, you wanna ask Allen Institute for this

Answer (score -2):

Try simply `dictionary = dict(your_dictionary_string)`.
If that doesn’t work, use the `json` module and `json.loads(your_dictionary_string)`

Comment: `dict(dict_repr_or_json)` will *not* be happy, it'll be a `ValueError`: *"dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"*.

Comment: true, before you pass it to ‘dict’ you should replace null with None, and so on. or just use json.loads().

Comment: that's not what I'm talking about, `dict("{'foo': None}")` would be unhappy for the same reason.

Answer (score -4):

You could try splitting the input string on comma's like:

```
ps = input_string.spit(",")
```

The split each element of ps on colon mlike:

```
for seg in ps:
  k = seg.split(":")
  out_dict[k[0]] = k[1]
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend *not* trying to reimplement JSON parsing.